# invalid value for parameter "client_encoding": "utf8mb4" (SQL: select * from "tablename") when deploy laravel to heroku

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, heroku

I am trying to deploy my laravel app to heroku but it returns an error:

```
SQLSTATE[22023]: Invalid parameter value: 7 ERROR: invalid value for parameter "client_encoding": "utf8mb4" (SQL: select * from "tablename").
```

I changed my tablename collation and columns from `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` to `utf8unicode_ci` but nothing happened. Please help me. I tried all the possible solutions I've searched but nothing really works.

Comment: Are you using a Postgres database?

Comment: @DilipHirapara At first, I used it. but since it returns error I tried to migrate to mysql but I am still getting the same error. What should i do?

Comment: Check in `config/database.php` that (i) the correct `default connection` is being used in `production` and (ii) that the connection `charset` is `utf8` and not `utf8mb4`

Comment: @DilipHirapara I tried to change the utf8mb4 to utf8 but nothing happened. Any other solution?

Comment: One more thing after change database.php file have you cleared the caches?

Comment: @DilipHirapara not yet. what is the command for that?

Comment: `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: @DilipHirapara I tried. but still  not worked

Comment: I had a similar problem in my rails app where locally I'd have a MySQL and I had to make sure that production was not configured to use the Mysql database.

Answer (score 9):

I have faced the same problem. Mistakenly i have not added `DB_CONNECTION=pgsql` in config vars on Heroku dashboard. **Inside setting tab** click on **Reveal Config Vars** and add `DB_CONNECTION=pgsql` there.

Another way just simply add **config vars** using terminal.

```
 heroku config:add DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
```

Comment: worked on mine! thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

After setting up your psql details as specified up there on config/database.php
run

```
git push origin master
git push heroku master
```

And try run the bash again..

```
heroku run bash
php artisan migrate:fresh
yes
```

and you're good to go

Answer (score 2):

> Laravel Databse Connection Environment issue

You are probably using the Postgresql as the Database instead of MySql.
Then please configure the database config in `config/database.php` file

> 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql')
>
> or set the DB_CONNECTION in .env as pgsql

pgsql will not support utf8mb4, it is for the MySQL, if you are using Postgresql pls correct the connection environment.

Answer (score 1):

##### For mysql:

```
[
    'database.connections.rds' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => $endpoint,
        'port' => $port,
        'database' => $db_name,
        'username' => $user,
        'password' => $password,
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ]
]
```

##### for Postgres

```
[
    'database.connections.rds' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => $endpoint,
        'port' => $port,
        'database' => $db_name,
        'username' => $user,
        'password' => $password,
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using laravel/telescope?
I had the same problem when trying to implement my project. To resolve the error, I removed laravel/telescope from my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
'mysql' => [
        // ...
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        // ...
],
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens at the environment variable configuration level on Heroku if you haven't done `key = DB_CONNECTION` and `value = pgsql`.

Answer (score -1):

In config/database.php, Use default connection
'default' => 'pgsql',
"client_encoding": "utf8"

If you are using MySQL than change default connection to 
'default' => 'mysql',
"client_encoding": "utf8mb4"